# PhpStorm: Insert parameter list on auto completion?

Tags: php, autocomplete, phpstorm, code-completion

Is it possible to get the full list of parameters of a function/method via auto completion?

Example:

```
class foo{

  public function __construct($param1, $param2, $param3 = null){
  }

}
```

Typing `new f` and using `CTRL+Space` to auto-complete, only `new foo();` is inserted.

I would like to get `new foo($param1, $param2);` or (maybe via setting for optional parameters) `new foo($param1, $param2, $param3);` - Eclipse PDT does this for example.

I couldn't find anything in the docs for [Auto-Completing Code](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/auto-completing-code.html) or [Editor Code Completion](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/editor-code-completion.html).

**//edit**

Seems not to be possible for the moment, see @LazyOne's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25445886/413531). Please upvote http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6984 and http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-18621 to draw some attention to this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is currently not possible.

You can check these tickets (and those that are marked as related):

- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-18621
- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-24156
- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-6000
- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6984
- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5575

As you can see such approach is definitely not a priority in IDEA-based IDEs.

Comment: Thanks!
Voted for http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6984 and http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-18621 since they have the most upvotes. I really hope this is going to be implemented.

Comment: and [now it is possible!](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2016/07/parameter-code-completion-in-phpstorm-2016-2/)